# How to determine which CPUs are online on Linux

Tags: c, linux

On Linux the C functions `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF)` and `get_nprocs_conf()` return the number of logical processors configured in the system, while `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` and `get_nprocs()` return the number of logical processors currently available.

Their values may be different as systems with hotpluggable CPUs may add/remove CPUs.

I would like to know exactly which logical processors are available, so I can avoid calling `sched_setaffinity()` with affinity set to logical processors that are configured but not available.

Is there a user mode function that lists the CPU IDs or gives a mask with all available CPUs?

Or if there is no such user mode function, how safe is it to assume the number configured and available CPUs are the same?

Comment: Would a quick and dirty parsing of /proc/cpuinfo work for you ?

Comment: Preferably not, as that involves parsing text. I'm looking for a fast native function.
Searching the web I found `for_each_cpu` but my Debian Linux doesn't seem to have that (or maybe it's only for kernel development).

Comment: `I'm looking for a fast native function`  Write your own kernel module. `found for_each_cpu` `for_each_cpu` is a function _inside_ kernel source. It's not available outside.

Comment: I'm just looking on how to access this information from user mode.
Or is it safe to assume in user mode configured and available CPUs are the same?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are any APIs to get that information but in userspace you can just use the [/sys/devices/system/cpu/](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu) to get various CPU information

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/offline # get the list of offline CPUs
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online  # get the list of online CPUs
ls -ld /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu* # get the list of CPUs
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online # print individual CPU's online/offline status
```

In C you can open those files and parse their contents

See also [CPU hotplug in the Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html)

Comment: I wanted to avoid parsing files, but your last suggestion seams quite easy as each file contains just 0 or 1. 
However cpu0 doesn't seem to be included. When I run `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online|wc -l` on my system I get 19 while I have 20 logical processors.

Comment: @BrechtSanders that's weird. I've check many systems and there's always CPU0. I myself don't like reading sysfs either, but many projects in my company do use it to read data

Comment: Yes there's always a CPU0, but onder most circumstances it can't be brought offline, so there is no `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online` status

Answer (score 2):

In [`/sys/devices/system/cpu`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-system-cpu), there are various pseudo-files for querying and taking `cpu`s online/offline. `/sys/devices/system/cpu/online` gives you a comma-separated list of ranges:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
0-6,8-9,11,13-15
```

You can get expand the ranges with something like this:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",",$1..$2)/eg' /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,13,14,15
```